# Dynamically added textView inside fragment gives null reference

Tags: android, view

So essentially, I'm making a quiz app and at the end of the app I have a method that is supposed to display the progress of the user. Essentially I would like to add textViews for every incorrect Answer that the user put in but it's telling me that they are all null. Here is the code:

```
public void progFinish() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        View view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_progress, null);

        TextView title = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.title_dialog);
        int total = wrongChars.size();
        LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) mView.findViewById(R.id.prog_dialog);

        for(Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : wrongChars.entrySet()) {
            Log.d("test", entry.getKey());
            TextView wrongChar = new TextView(getActivity());
            wrongChar.setText(entry.getKey() + " \t" + entry.getValue() + " ");
            wrongChar.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            linearLayout.addView(wrongChar);
        }

        builder.setView(view);
        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();

    }
```

I'm unsure of the issue at hand here. It is important to note that there is a member variable

```
protected View mView
```

which is initialized in onViewCreated. Is there a particular reason that they are null? I am going to assume it is because of mView - but I am unsure.

This is the line that returns the error:

```
linearLayout.addView(wrongChar);

Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.LinearLayout.addView(android.view.View)' on a null object reference
```

Edit: Important to note that the textview which is statically inside the layout is inflated just fine(will show when user doesn't get anything wrong.) So I think it is safe to assume that the dynamically added textViews are the issue at hand. Not sure why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that when you use:

```
findViewById(R.id.name_of_view);
```

you will return a view that's inside the activity/fragments layout. In my case, since it was a dialog and the layout at hand was different from the fragment, it was returning null as there was no linearlayout with that ID present.

To fix it, I simply changed it to:

```
        View view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_progress, null);
        LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.prog_dialog);
```

And now it was properly referencing the right linear layout.